# Missing Syntax of moving file from one folder to another

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file

what is missing in this command ?

```
find source/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name Master.csv.2016-08-*.csv -exec mv -n {} backup/07-16;
```

when I run this command, I am getting wrong

```
Error :--find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Comment: `... backup/07-16 \;` should do it.

Comment: not working . i tried.                                                                                 find source/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name Master.csv.2016-08-*.csv -exec mv -n {} backup/07-16\;

Comment: you need a space before `\;`

Comment: @fedorqui thank u so much